# Is it possible to listen to ANY IP address?

Tags: networking

May I listen to *any* ip address from a java application?

Please note that I do not mean to say *any existing local address*.

I'm talking about *any ip address*.

I have a network interface receiving traffic mirrored from a certain link, and the destination IP address will vary "randomly", but I want to be able to get those packets to be sent to my java application.

Thanks.
-Bob

Answer (score 1):

With the library jpcap you can sniffing all packages incoming and outgoing from a network interface.
http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

Or perhaps you need Java Sockets.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I'm using netty as my networking framework. I'm not sure if I can use jpcap from within netty itself. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open ended question, can you be a little more specific?

The answer is yes, you can listen to any IP address that the network stack of your hosting OS can see (even if it's not for the network card in the system but modern switching will limit how useful that is, see promiscuous network).

Try using 0.0.0.0 as the expected address in your configuration but it seems like there is something missing on your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Well, I'll try to be more specific.  I'm using ubuntu 14.04.  As far as I know, promiscuous mode only works at the MAC level, not at the IP level. So, yes, my interface will be set to promiscuous mode, but I guess my application won't get called at all because the destination IP address will not match to any of my local addresses. If I use 0.0.0.0, that means all my IP addresses, but any other IP will not match. That is why 0.0.0.0 does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @BobV., If you can capture at the MAC level (layer-2), you will get all the layers above it, including IP (layer-3), since layer-2 encapsulates layer-3, which encapsulates layer-4, which encapsulates the application layers. You only need to get the payload of a frame which has an ethertype of `0x0800` for IPv4 or `0x86DD` for IPv6 to get the IP packet, and the destination IP address is in the packet header.

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes, I know that. But that does not mean that my application will get notified if the destination IP address of the received packet does not match with the ones my application is listening on. My understanding is that the layer 3 of my stack will drop the packet silently when it checks that no one is listening on that particular destination IP address. That is why I'm asking about the way of listening on any potential address received. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but who cares if you are capturing the traffic at layer-2? Your network stack rightly doesn't want to pass the traffic up if it doesn't belong to your host, but it will not reach out and grab back what you have captured at layer-2.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But my feeling is that even if the packet has been captured at layer 2, my application won't be able to receive it because IP layer will drop it. Promiscuous mode allows me to bypass layer 2 checks, but layer 3 checks will make my app unable to receive spurious packets. I could workaround it by means of iptables, changing the destination address to one associated to my system, but this does not work for me, since I need the original source IP address to perform some calculations within my application.

Comment: @BobV., when you capture a layer-2 frame, you can do anything you want with it. I think your problem is that you are trying to use the network stack to send the packet to your application. You should just capture the frame, decode what you want, and use the results of that in your application. You will not be able to use the network stack to process packets not destined for the network addresses assigned to the network stack. Basically, you are capturing a copy of the frames o that you can use the encapsulated data for your own purposes.